# Table Scroll issue in Firefox and not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to freeze the left most column and header in table.
I am able to achieve it and it works perfectly fine in chrome but not so perfectly in firefox.
The problem is that while scrolling to the right (left column remains freeze) but the header scrolls at slower rate than body giving a shaddow effect on the table.The header and Body are not in sync while scrolling to the left

Finally This JavaScript Tag is responsible for stutter while scrolling to the left on Mozilla and IE what optimization can I Apply ?

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#resultBlock').scroll(function(e) { 
            $('#headerBlock').css("right", $('#resultBlock').scrollLeft()); 
            $('#resultBlock').find("th:nth-child(1)").css("left", $(this).scrollLeft());
            $('#resultBlock').find("th:nth-child(2)").css("left", $(this).scrollLeft());

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to share your code

Comment: We can't help you if you can share your code problem with us.

Comment: From What I Found ScrollLeft jquery Function runs slower on IE and mozilla as compared to Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example using DataTable Js.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY: "200px",
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1,
      leftColumns: 2
    }
  });
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.order-column {
  background: #fff;
}

.dataTables_filter,
.dataTables_info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod</td>
      <td>Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
      <td>9608</td>
      <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona</td>
      <td>Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
      <td>6200</td>
      <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen</td>
      <td>Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
      <td>2360</td>
      <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya</td>
      <td>Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
      <td>1667</td>
      <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena</td>
      <td>Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
      <td>3814</td>
      <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn</td>
      <td>Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
      <td>9497</td>
      <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde</td>
      <td>Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
      <td>6741</td>
      <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley</td>
      <td>Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
      <td>3597</td>
      <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana</td>
      <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
      <td>1965</td>
      <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
      <td>1581</td>
      <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
      <td>3059</td>
      <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria</td>
      <td>Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
      <td>1721</td>
      <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
      <td>2558</td>
      <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai</td>
      <td>Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
      <td>2290</td>
      <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette</td>
      <td>Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
      <td>1937</td>
      <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri</td>
      <td>Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
      <td>6154</td>
      <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar</td>
      <td>Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
      <td>8330</td>
      <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris</td>
      <td>Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
      <td>3023</td>
      <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica</td>
      <td>Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
      <td>5797</td>
      <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin</td>
      <td>Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
      <td>8822</td>
      <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
      <td>9239</td>
      <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden</td>
      <td>Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
      <td>1314</td>
      <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
      <td>2947</td>
      <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou</td>
      <td>Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
      <td>8899</td>
      <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle</td>
      <td>House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
      <td>2769</td>
      <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki</td>
      <td>Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
      <td>6832</td>
      <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott</td>
      <td>Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
      <td>3606</td>
      <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin</td>
      <td>Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
      <td>2860</td>
      <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena</td>
      <td>Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
      <td>8240</td>
      <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
      <td>5384</td>
      <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard</td>
      <td>Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
      <td>7031</td>
      <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope</td>
      <td>Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
      <td>6318</td>
      <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian</td>
      <td>Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
      <td>9422</td>
      <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy</td>
      <td>Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
      <td>7580</td>
      <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
      <td>1042</td>
      <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia</td>
      <td>Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
      <td>2120</td>
      <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno</td>
      <td>Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
      <td>6222</td>
      <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura</td>
      <td>Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
      <td>9383</td>
      <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor</td>
      <td>Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
      <td>8327</td>
      <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn</td>
      <td>Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
      <td>2927</td>
      <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge</td>
      <td>Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
      <td>8352</td>
      <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
      <td>7439</td>
      <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita</td>
      <td>Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
      <td>4389</td>
      <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
      <td>3431</td>
      <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara</td>
      <td>Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
      <td>3990</td>
      <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
      <td>1016</td>
      <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
      <td>6733</td>
      <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas</td>
      <td>Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
      <td>8196</td>
      <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad</td>
      <td>Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
      <td>6373</td>
      <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
      <td>5384</td>
      <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna</td>
      <td>Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
      <td>4226</td>
      <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```